# Implementing box2d debug draw with pixijs?

Tags: box2d, box2dweb, pixi.js

I have used box2d in flash. I am trying to implement it for an html5 game. I intend to use pixijs as rendering engine for my game. Does anybody know how to get the debug draw working for pixijs.

While googling the topic I cam across 
https://gist.github.com/cbranch/260224a7e4699552d2dc

How every I am unable to get it working.